# Does naming a person according to vedic astrology have any benefits

Tags: vedanta, astrology, vedic-rituals, manuscripts, horary-astrology

I have seen so many astrology sites suggesting names for specific kundali. Does naming someone according to vedic astrology hold any specific benefits according to the so called swara siddhantha.